# Is it good practice to compare string values of two comboboxes c#

Tags: c#

I want to compare values of two comboboxes. The variables are of type var and they come like this: 27-12-2018
I want to compare these two values and for this purpose I have converted the value in date format and in string format.

This is meteorologycal charts.

```
var formattedDates = string.Join("_", Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_', '.').Skip(1).Take(3));
var formattedDates2 = string.Join("_", Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_', '.').Skip(1).Take(3));                    

if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(formattedName))
{
    comboBox2.Items.Add(formattedName);
}

if (!comboBox3.Items.Contains(formattedDates))
{
    comboBox3.Items.Add(formattedDates);
}

if (!comboBox4.Items.Contains(formattedDates2))
{
    comboBox4.Items.Add(formattedDates2);
}

listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));     
}               
}

else    
{
    MessageBox.Show("Директорията Meteo не е октирта в системен диск 'C:\'");
    Application.ExitThread();
}

var result = Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Meteo", "*.dat")
            .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))
            .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .Select(items => new {
                  id = items[0],
                  date = DateTime.ParseExact(items[1], "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(),
                  date2 = items[1],
                  hours = items[2],
                  temperature = items[3],
                  presure = items[4],
                  windSpeed = items[5],
                  windDirect = items[6],
                  rain = items[7],
                  rainIntensity = items[8],
                  sunRadiation = items[12],

                  /* etc. */
              })
              .ToList();

            var dates = result
           .Select(item => item.date)
           .ToArray();
```

I have the same values in two formats - String and Date, but I dont know how to compare two comboboxes (if firstCombo > secondCombo){ messagebox.show("")}

Comment: Try converting your string to date: [`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8) or casting your date to a string using `String.Format`

Comment: No variable is ever of "type var" in C#. When you declare a variable with `var`, the compiler *must* be able to infer what the type is, otherwise it will not compile. `var` is just a shorthand for the full type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your string to a DateTime type.

```
DateTime DT1 = DateTime.ParseExact("18/08/2015 06:30:15.006542", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Rearrange the format string to match whatever date format you are using. 
Then you can just do:

```
if(DT1 > DT2)
```

Also FYI, VAR isnt a type, it just sets the type of the variable to whatever type is on the right side of the equals.

Answer (score 0):

To compare values of two comboboxes, you first need to convert both values into a type that can be compared. In your case, you seem to want to compare dates.

`Ex: 07-06-2019 > 06-06-2019 = True.`

I would recommend you to get the current values from both comboboxes (`combobox.Text`) and create a `DateTime` object with them.

Then, you'll be able to compare them like you want.

```
DateTime date0 = Convert.ToDateTime(combobox0.Text);//"07-06-2019"
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(combobox1.Text);//"06-06-2019"
int value = DateTime.Compare(date0, date1);

if (value > 0)
{
    //date0 > date1
}
else
{
    if (value < 0)
    {
        //date0 < date1
    }
    else
    {
        //date0 == date1
    }
}
```

Finally, to answer your question, the best practice to compare combobox values is depending on what value you're trying to compare... If you want to compare dates like in your example, it is better to convert the values to DateTime. The only comparison you can make with strings, correct me if I'm wrong, is to check if the strings are equal or have the same value.

Another good practice is to use the `TryParse` method associated to the type of value you want to convert/compare. Most of, if not all, basic types in c# have this method associated to them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

```
DateTime date0;

//Take text from combobox0, convert it and put the result in date0
bool success = DateTime.TryParse(combobox0.Text, out date0);

if(success)
{
    //Your date has been converted properly
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: at WindowsFormsApp1.frm_main.frm_main_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MeteoAnalyzer - D.Atanasov\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\frm_main.cs:line 104

At this code:

 DateTime date0;

                    //Take string value from combobox0, convert it and put the result in date0
                    bool success = DateTime.TryParse(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString(), out date0);

Comment: @BenJohnson have you tried changing `combobox3.SelectedValue.ToString()` for `combobox3.Text`?